# Should I use elseif or multiple if clauses

Tags: php

I have this simple if code:

Which is better, doing it with esleif or doing two separate ifs?

```
if(is_home() && $currentpage == ''){ 
    $catname = 'cars';
} elseif(is_home() && $currentpage != '' && is_page_template('models.php')){ 
    $catname = 'newcars';
}
```

Two separete if clauses:

```
if(is_home() && $currentpage == ''){ 
    $catname = 'cars';
} 
if(is_home() && $currentpage != '' && is_page_template('models.php')){ 
    $catname = 'newcars';
}
```

Does the order of if matters? could I place the second if before first?
The question should have been how php treats conditions from more particular to more general?
Should you always start with the more particular ones and work your way up to general? 
Or php can sort them through?

The second version would be easier for me since I have allot of if's:)

Comment: Else ifs are mutually exclusive if statements. Multiple ifs are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends what behaviour you want:

If you use `elseif`, **only** the first matching block will execute.

```
$foo = $bar = true;
if($foo) { /* executed */ }
elseif($bar) { /* not executed */ }
```

When using separate `if` claused, all matching blocks will execute:

```
$foo = $bar = true;
if($foo) { /* executed */ }
if($bar) { /* also executed */ }
```

If the conditions are distinct, i.e. only one is ever true it doesn't really matter. However, by using `elseif` you avoid useless checks since as soon as one condition evaluates to true no further conditions need to be checked.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know, so if the first is a particular query and the second one is more general, if I use two ifs the general one could override the more particular one

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of script optimization, I would recommend elseifs as to avoid running extra unnecessary conditionals.

If possible, I would recommend the use of switch/case statements (where you can check the value of a single variable). They're cleaner and easier to maintain from a reduce clutter point of view.

One problem with multiple if statements (instead of elseif statements) is it makes debugging issues more complicated. How are you to know that the second statement isn't overriding the first statement or that your conditional logic is correct for every statement? Using multiple ifs increases the likelihood that one conditional overrides the function of another. Start adding multiple variables inside these if statements and it'll start to hurt your brain.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_home()) { 

    if ($currentpage == '') {

        $catname = 'cars';
    }
    else if (is_page_template('models.php')) {

        $catname = 'newcars';
    }       
}
```

Comment: I think it is ugly because it adds more nested code. And it doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

i would go with,

```
if(is_home()) {
    if($currentpage == '') {
        $catname = 'cars';
    }
    elseif(is_page_template('models.php')) { 
        $catname = 'newcars';
    }
}
```